# How to estimate gamma and cost parameters for SVM quickly

Tags: r, svm, caret, e1071

I want to train SVMs in R and I know there are functions such as `e1071::tune.svm()` that can be used to find the optimal parameters for the SVM. However, it seems there are some formulas out there (e.g. used in [this report](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/aistats/fullpapers/198.pdf)) that can give you a reasonable estimate of these parameters.
Since a grid-search for the parameters can take quite a lot of time on larger datasets and usually, one has to provide a range of possible values anyway, I wondered whether there is a package that implements formulas to get a quick estimate for the `gamma` and `cost` parameters for the SVM?

So far, I've found out that `caret::train()` might use such an approach to estimate `sigma` (which should be the reciprocal of 2*`gamma`^2) but I haven't tried it yet, since other calculations are still running (and will be, probably for the next days). Is there also an implementation to estimate `cost` or at least give a range of reasonable values?

I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43481994/11611246) that asks for alternatives to grid-search in general. However, I would be interested in an R implementation of such alternatives and also, I hope things have developed further since the more general question was posted years ago.